# Why is $e$ transcendental, even though it can be written as a sum of algebraic numbers?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

I am, of course, referring to the Maclaurin series for $e$ evaluated at $1$. Then we have $$e = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}...$$Then $e$ is the sum of an infinite series of algebraic numbers, which would imply $e$ is algebraic. What am I missing? Is it the fact that the sum is infinite? I know $e$ is transcendental because it cannot be expressed by a polynomial with integer coefficients, so why is it that it can be expressed by a sum of algebraic numbers?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is not a sum, it is a limit.

Comment: Every real number is a "infinite sum" of algebraic numbers, i.e., the decimal representation of a number.

Comment: $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\cdots$$ looks more like $e-1$ to me.

Comment: You might also ask yourself, Ty, how the set of positive integers can be an infinite set, when it's a union of finite sets, $\{1\}\cup\{2\}\cup\{3\}\cup\cdots$.

Comment: And as it turns out, it’s pretty trivial after all!

Comment: @JonasGomes that makes a ton of sense and it clears up my point of confusion, and also makes sense thinking of $e$ as the limit rather than a sum, i.e. $S_{n \rightarrow \infty}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What, essentially, you are wondering is why limits do not preserve algebraicity. Specifically, you have noted that even though the partial sums $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac1{k!}$$
are all rational, their limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=e$ is not.

And frankly, this is the case because of the way we have defined real numbers. That is, any $x\in\Bbb R$ can be written as a decimal $$x=p.q_1q_2q_3...$$
where $p\in\Bbb Z$ and $q_k\in\{0,1,...,9\}$. Hence every number $$a_M=p.q_1...q_M=10^{-M}\lfloor 10^M x\rfloor$$
is rational and the sequence $(a_M)_{M\ge0}$ converges to $x$. In other words, every real number, regardless of whether or not it's rational, has a sequence of rationals which converges to it.

So that, I guess, means that being the limit of a rational sequence isn't a very interesting property, unless you're into that kind of thing.

At the end of the day, it turns out that transcendence and being the limit of a rational sequence have actually nothing to do with each other, even though it may seem like they might at the surface level. For a really nice transcendence proof of $e$ (and $\pi$), check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyoH_vgiqXM) by the wonderful mathematics youtuber Mathologer.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you so much, it makes complete sense and that video is also great.

Comment: @TyJensen I am very glad you enjoyed it! Thank you for asking such a good question :)